# BASh - Convert list of hex values to binary file (application)

Tags: bash, hex, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have a file containing hex representations of code from a small program, and am trying to actually convert it into the program itself.

For example, here is a sample of such text, stored in a file, `input.txt`:

```
8d
00
a1
21
53
57
43
48
0e
00
bb
```

I am using the following BASh snippet to convert the file to a binary file:

```
rm outfile; while read h; do echo -n ${h}; echo -ne \\x${h} >> outfile; done < input.txt
```

After opening the output file in VIM:

```
¡!SWCH»
```

And then converting it to hex representation via `xxd`:

```
0000000: 8d00 a121 5357 4348 0e00 bb0a            ...!SWCH....
```

This is all good, except for one thing: There is a trailing byte, **`0a`**, trailing at the end of my binary output file. This happens for every program file I work with. How is the trailing `0a` being appending to every output binary file? It's not present in my input file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, use xxd directly from a bash like

```
xxd outfile > outfile.hex
```

and you will see, here isn't any `0a`.

The `0a` is appended somewhere when the vim sends a line to xxd command. If you want convert inside vim - try use

```
vim -b outfile
```

what open the `outfile` in binary mode.